# Concat two variables into new variable

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

I want to set privileges to some specific tables. These tablesNames are stored in a variable(tableName) like the schemas (schemaName) aswell. My mission is to concatinate these variables to schemaName.tableName .

I've tried to concatinate these variables, but I'm ending into getting an variable is not defined.

```
  GRANT SELECT ON schemaName || "." || tableName TO roleName;
```

Is there any way to use variable variables like in PHP? [example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using a static statement. The GRANT statement does not allow the use of variables for schema or table name.

In a stored procedure you can use a dynamic statement instead. Something like:

```
DECLARE stmt VARCHAR(100);

...

SET stmt = 'GRANT SELECT ON '  || schemaName || '.' || tableName ||
           ' TO ' || rolename;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
```